# OpenVPN used to work, now can't ping 10.8.0.1

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, openvpn

Please help!

I had OpenVPN configured and working on a server 2012 with windows clients. After a restart I can't ping 10.8.0.1 anymore - neither on client nor server.

It's unlikely that config's been changed. What MAY have changed is the IP's of the client. I think they used to be .4 and .8 (as in ipp.txt). Now they're .6 and .10 but I can't get them back. It could be that they really were .6 and .10 when everything was working also.

One more thing MAY be different on the server log file, compared to an old saved log file that I know worked:

```
Thu Aug 11 15:14:22 2016 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.2
Thu Aug 11 15:14:22 2016 Warning: route gateway is not reachable on any active network adapters: 10.8.0.2
Thu Aug 11 15:14:22 2016 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Thu Aug 11 15:14:22 2016 Route addition fallback to route.exe
OK!
```

That used to be:

```
Fri May 27 18:16:54 2016 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.2
Fri May 27 18:16:54 2016 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=30 and dwForwardType=4
Fri May 27 18:16:54 2016 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
```

The route is there though, according to `route print`.

As I said, I can't be absolutely sure any of these clues have anything to do with it.

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I've never had this in my config before:

```
route-method exe
route-delay 2
```

But I tried it following the advice of @cormpadre. The log now shows

```
Thu Aug 11 15:56:48 2016 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.2
OK!
```

but still no ping.

**Edit 2 - Experiments with Wireshark**

Got wireshark listening on both client and server, on VPN adapters and LAN/internet adapters while pinging.

Client pings 10.8.0.1.

ICMP packets on client VPN adapter. No response.

UPD packets on client LAN adapter. Getting responses.

UPD packets on server LAN adapter. Sending responses.

No packets on server VPN adapter.

Server pings 10.8.0.6 and 10.8.0.1.

I deem only control packets on server LAN adapter. These are sent regardless 
and ping packets tend to be 101 bytes when they're UDP-wrapped.

Nothing on the server VPN adapter. Ever. Flat line.

**Edit 3**

Found out how to tune Wireshark to OpenVPN packets. Those UDP packets turned out to P_DATA_V1 types. The control packets seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr; Gateway on the server TAP-adapter is important.

Ah.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin>tapinstall.exe remove tap0901
```

Did I in my efforts restart the server and clients?

Of course I did.

Did I uninstall/reinstall OpenVPN on both server and clients?

Elementary.

What I did not do until just now was delete my TAP-adapters before reinstalling. It seems somehow I lost the proper configuration on the server TAP-adapter at some point.  I don't know how and I don't know exactly what part. But there you go.

The above will do just that.

**However...**

After another restart I was back to square one. Then I started thinking, what could that particular config be that was so wrong?

This lead me to, find my TAP-adapter, enter properties and IPV4 properties. Click advanced and add the gateway, the one that shows up if you do a `route print`, in my case 10.8.0.2.

So try that first.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps which resolved the issue mentioned by Martin.

1. Backup C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config
2. Uninstall tap adapter and openvpn from add/remove programs
3. Reboot computer
4. Download and install latest OpenVpn package (openvpn-install-2.4.7-I607-Win7.exe)
5. Copy the backup config to C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config
6. Start the OpenVpnService service and change to automatic startup.
7. Check C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\log\server.log

`Successful ARP Flush on interface [12] {36785BD5-BF1D-4430-90EA-1E32927ED68F}`

`C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.2`

`ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=10 and dwForwardType=4`

`Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]`

8. Connect using OpenVPN Client.

Hope that helps.

Regards,

Andy.

Comment: So essentially, do you think an update is needed, or that the installation was broken and a reinstall will fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the end of the configuration (ovpn) file:

`route-method exe
route-delay 2`

Failing that try the usual windows networking stuff:
`netsh dump
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset log.txt
ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Can you edit question with the new section of log?

Comment: I tried your first suggestion. The log looks a bit different. Still can't ping 10.8.0.1 on server or client. Will return with more results.

Comment: Did "the usual windows networking stuff" to no avail. On a client. Should I do it on the server as well?

Comment: If others can connect to server i wouldnt imagine the problem is there. But it sounds like possibly something in your firewall config. Have you disabled your firewall to test on the client?

Comment: Nobody can connect to the server anymore. All firewalls on clients are disabled. On server only using AWS firewall.

Comment: Check out my wireshark experiments.

Comment: It sounds a lot like there is something blocking on the server side. maybe a router or firewall. Sorry but different issue than i thought. are there any server logs indicating attempts to connect?

Comment: Apart from the wireshark capture? I don't know. What are you suggesting?